# Parser error when trying to generate gauge chart

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to generate a gauge chart based on changing MTBF values, However when I run the webapplication, I get the error

Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: 'WebApplication1.WebForm3' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error:

Line 1:
Line 2:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm3" %>
Line 3:
Line 4:

Source File: /WebForm3.aspx    Line: 2

THe code that i have used is as follows,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebApplication1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            using (Testme entities = new Testme())
            {



                var execution = entities.TestExecutionDetails.Where(p => p.TestExecutionID == TestExecID).Select(p => p).OrderBy(p => p.StartTime).ToArray();
                var failures = entities.TestExecutionDetails.Select(p => p.Result != "Pass      ").Count();

                var uptime = entities.TestExecutionDetails.Where(p => p.Result == "Pass          ").Select(p => p);
                TimeSpan elapsedDuration = new TimeSpan(0);
                foreach (var p in uptime)
                {

                    elapsedDuration += (p.EndTime.Value - p.StartTime.Value);

                }
                var mtbfdisplay = elapsedDuration.TotalSeconds / failures;


                string str1 = @"

        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([";

                string str2 = @"['Label', 'Value'],['MTBF'," + mtbfdisplay + @"],]);";

                string str3 = @"var options = {
                width: 400, height: 120, redFrom: 90, redTo: 100, yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90, minorTicks: 5
            };


                var chart = new google.visualization.gauge(document.getelementbyid('chart-success'));
                chart.draw(data, options);";

                string postData = str1 + str2 + str3;

                Console.WriteLine(postData);


                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "test", postData, true);

            }


        }
    }
}
```

The aspx code is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label>
                <br />
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value="1" />
                <br />

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="1"></asp:Label>
                <br />

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

                <div id="chart-success"></div>

            </ContentTemplate>


        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm really stuck, I don't even know if this is the right approach to generate the charts, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `WebForm3` is not declared anywhere (at least in the code that you have posted), so most likely this line:

```
public partial class WebApplication1 : System.Web.UI.Page
```

should be

```
public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was really a big thing to overlook..thanks again!

Comment: Now, I dont know why the chart is not getting generated :( , can you give me any pointers for that please?

Comment: @Archer, never worked with this API before, but most likely it has something to do with the update panel. Try doing the same thing without one. If you still have problems with this - it would be a good idea not to mix questions and post a separate one, describing in details meaning of "chart is not getting generated".

Comment: Thank you Andrei, will post a different question

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but no one seems to answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039350/google-gauge-chart-not-getting-generated-in-asp around this, is the question ambiguous or badly written? Pls let me know, so that I can rectify.